# Integral not giving expected answer

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Below is the integral I'm trying to evaluate:

```
FullSimplify[
  Integrate[
    Sin[θ]/(1 + (4 k^2)/(μ^2)(Sin[θ/2])^2), 
    {θ, 0, Pi}, 
    Assumptions -> {Element[{μ, k}, Reals]}]]
```

It is out of a book for which I have the solution manual, and the solution appears to show that this integral should evaluate to something like:

```
2*μ^2 / (μ^2 + 4k^2)
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not know how you get the answer you post $2 \frac{\mu^2}{\mu^2+4 k^2}$, but if you tell *Mathematica* that both $\mu,\theta$ are either positive or negative at the same time, you get a similar answer but one that has a $\log$ in it:

```
Clear[x, mu,k]
integrand = Sin[x]/(1 + (4 k^2)/mu^2 (Sin[x/2])^2);
Assuming[ Element[{mu, k}, Reals] && {mu, k} > 0, Integrate[integrand, {x, 0, Pi}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Ah, yes. Looks like I forgot to square the denominator, hah